# check condition for two column in two different dataframes in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose there is one column in dataframe and there is similar schema column in another dataframe. how to check check the values consisting in the columns are same or not without joining them as there is not common attribute.

**DF1**
serial_nm
abc
mnc
pqr

**DF2**
ser_nm
hgf
mnc
uio
pqr
lok

And i want third DF3 as output 
**DF3**
mnc
pqr

I tried this

```
  val DF3 = DF1.filter(DF1("serial_nm") === DF2("ser_nm"))
```

But its not working

Please Help
Thanks..!!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a join? You could do `DF1.join(DF2, DF1("serial_nm") === DF2("ser_nm"))`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use a join. Consider using it like this:

```
val DF3 = DF1.join(DF2, DF1("serial_nm") === DF2("ser_nm"))
```

or

```
val DF3 = DF1.join(DF2).where(DF1("serial_nm") === DF2("ser_nm"))
```

Both approaches are quivalent.

Note: To avoid problems with ambiguous columns, one option is to rename them before the join:

```
val df2_renamed = DF2
  .withColumnRenamed("mnc", "df2_mnc")
  .withColumnRenamed("pqr", "df2_pqr")
```

Comment: Ya it can be the case.. but still i am not the output which i am trying on a cluster.

Comment: @Tejaswagh why isn't it working? What problem are you encountering?